# Get selected folder path from a folder browsing dialog in mvc4

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I want the user to select a folder location on his machine. I need to get that selected folder path. Is there any control in mvc4 to achieve my requirement. Please help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This makes no sense.  Are you talking about within a webpage?  Client side or server side?  Yeech.

Comment: Do you mean you want to be able to select a folder within the browser, then send that path information to the server?

Comment: It may help you get a better answer if you include what you hope to achieve with this information - generally speaking a local file path is not much use to a remote server.

Comment: Yes, I want to select a local folder of the user from a web page. and read that path in my code

Comment: Do you expect to be able to access files within that folder?

Comment: No, I don't want files within that folder. I just need path of the folder selected

Comment: See my answer for details on how to achieve this - less than ideal, but of course local file system access is very limited over the web for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to store the text path a user has selected on their local machine, you only have 2 options.

1) Use an HTML file upload, and get them to upload a file. However some modern browsers will strip the full file path, leaving this of little use to you.

2) Write a flash or java plugin that lets them pick a local folder and include it on the page. You'll then have to ask the users to dismiss the dire security warnings that will be presented to them.

Unfortunately, due to security concerns, those are your only options for achieving this.